# WPF Change Window Style dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF Application with two Styles `BackButtonModernWindow` and `NoBackButtonModernWindow`.

Is it possible to change the `Windowstyle` on `ButtonClick` Event?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200902/changing-the-styles-at-runtime-in-wpf

Comment: @Nayan: Although the solution is similar, I would not mark the question as duplicate. Unlike the question you've posted, this is crystal clear and so is the answer and thus it is a good Q/A contribution to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use something like this in btn_click.

this.Style= Application.Current.FindResource("BackButtonModernWindow") as Style;