# C# wpf print with another (new) style and add custom images + header and footer

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

So I'm trying to print a datagrid with some other content inside of it (just a singel label), but I want to make a new lay-out for the print, with custom data and custom styling in it. This is what I currently get of lay-out when I print:

[image: Result]

From this page:

[image: system]

Now, What I do, is I have a `StackPanel` with the name `print_content`, which is inside of a grid and has a textblock in it. Code:

```
<Grid Margin="15,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Class selector and tour part selector-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Klasse</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox x:Name="inp_klasse" Margin="15,0" MinWidth="60" Height="auto" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Deel</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox x:Name="inp_tour_part" Margin="15,0" MinWidth="60" Height="auto" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button x:Name="Btn_print" Margin="15,0" MinWidth="60" Height="auto" Style="{StaticResource Button-default}" Content="Print"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,30" x:Name="print_content">

        <TextBlock x:Name="txt_selected_class" Text="KLASSE HIER" />

        <!--Here will the result come-->
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Now, that's not the problem, I just want to print the datagrid with the label (so the stackpanel), but **with NOT the default style**. The style should be another one. (No idea how I could do this), the print code I use (triggered on the print button) is the following:

```
private void Btn_print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog Printdlg = new PrintDialog();
    if ((bool)Printdlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        Size pageSize = new Size(Printdlg.PrintableAreaWidth, Printdlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
        // sizing of the element.
        print_content.Measure(pageSize);
        print_content.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
        Printdlg.PrintVisual(print_content, Title);
    }
}
```

So the main question is here; How can I make a custom lay-out with additional parameters (such as time of printing and images on the bottom and a text at the top) with another, not current, styling?

**Edit:**

It's not only the change of the style here, changing the style at runtime is a known solve, I need to make a PDF that looks like this at the output:

[image: result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the styles at runtime in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200902/changing-the-styles-at-runtime-in-wpf)

Comment: This doesn't help me any closer.... I want to make a custom "template"