# Restore dynamic resource value

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource

I have a textblock **tb** with style.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb"  Style="{DynamicResource H1Style}" Text="Test"/>
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key= "H1Style">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
</Style>
```

Then i change size

```
tb.FontSize = 5;
```

How do i restore style H1Style of tb?

I tried set **SetResourceReference**, but FontSize still 5 instead of 18.

```
tb.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "H1Style");
```

Comment: Please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18201435/10794016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line - `tb.FontSize = 5;` - assigns *local value* to FontSize property of TextBlock.  There is a way to undo assignment - [ClearValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.clearvalue) method:

```
 tb.ClearValue(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty);
```

FontSize is a dependency property and its value is computed according to [DP value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence)

There are 3 sources from DP value precedence list:

- local value `5`
- Style Setter value `18`
- default value of `FontSize` DP

`ClearValue()` removes local value, causes recompute, and next value is provided by Style Setter which has highest priority from present sources

Comment: Thx. This is exactly what i was looking for.